# Maven.I can run my JUnit Tests in IntelliJ but maven only reports that 0 tests executed

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project. This projects runs fine, I can start all my testcases with the IntelliJ Engine.

Now I tried to use the surefire plugin in order to start the tests from maven cli too. But I failed. I always get BUILD SUCCESS, but with the following output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried to follow all convention like naming the testclass with Test at the end and putting ist in src/test/java but it doesn't work.

Has anybody an idea what I have missed?

POM:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
      <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are your test classes public?

Comment: First I would use only a release version of JUnit Jupiter (5.7.0) and only the engine in your case which depends on the surefire version you are using...furthermore I doubt that you need maven-model as a dependency...Also I would recommend to migrate all the tests to JUnit Jupiter... open a lot more options...that JUnit 4 does.

Comment: I need maven model because I read some information from the POM.

But that does not affect my tests. How can I migrate all my tests to JUNIT Jupiter?

Answer (score 0):

After adding this dependency, it worked. I don't know exactly why but at least I have a solution:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```